# Java script file path is not identifying by Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, ascx

I need to access css and javascript files which are in sharepoint style library from ascx control. I stored custom css and javascript files in style lybrary and added below code in ascx. But the issue is sharepoint is **not** identifying the javascript files from the below given path.

Code in ascx

```
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" ID="MenuCSSLink" Version="4" ></SharePoint:CssLink>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/Style.css" EnableCssTheming="True" ID="css" runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLinkMenu1" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script1.js " ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLinkMenu2" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script2.min.js " ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLinkMenu3" runat="server" Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script3.js " ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptMenu6" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script4.js " ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

I tested the page with IE developer tool (F12) and found that css is rendering properly but not the js.
I kept the Java script in style library root flder and tested also. this one also not worked

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra space at the end of your JS links. It's escaping that space and adding %20 to your URL. If you View Source, you might see something like this:

```
document.write('<script src="/Style%20Library/en-us/Core%20Styles/JS/script1.js%20"></' + 'script>');
```

Removing that space should point to the proper file URL.

Comment: :- above code helped a bit to solve. Finally I am able to solve the issue. You can check the answer that I posted. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code as below

```
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" ID="MenuCSSLink" Version="4" DefaultUrl="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Themable/Style.css %>" ></SharePoint:CssLink>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/en-us/Themable/Style.css" EnableCssTheming="True" ID="css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLinkMenu1" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script1.js" Language="javascript" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLinkMenu2" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script2.min.js" Language="javascript" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptLinkMenu3" runat="server" Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script3.js" Language="javascript" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptMenu6" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/en-us/Core Styles/JS/script4.js" Language="javascript" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

And also to make theme functionality work in sharepoint, I stored the style sheet in themable folder in style library